# What is the difference between different normalization/serialization hooks in ember data?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

There are many hooks in ember data v1.0.0-beta.16.1.

Its just hard to understand the purpose of these hooks. To a novice it seems all of them are meant to do the same thing.

I am looking to understand applications of,

A. normalize and normalizeHash

B. serialize

C. normalizePayload

Answer (score 3):

The [docs](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html) explain them pretty well, but here is my take on it:

`normalize` is used to modify root object in incoming payload.

`normalizeHash` is used to modify individual object properties in incoming payload.

`serialize` is used to modify the outgoing object being sent to server.

`normalizedPayload` is used to remove extraneous data from incoming payload such as meta data.

Comment: `extractSingle` and `extractArray` are used to modify root objects. `normalize` is meant to work on individual hash as per docs, not on root objects. This gets confusing when people try to add their own purposes. *smh*

Comment: hm it is confusing. the docs say `If you want, you can just restructure the top-level of your payload, and do more fine-grained normalization in the *normalize* method.`

Comment: My bad, It was actualy in another accepted answer, someone said its meant for individual hash. Still then the purpose of extract hooks and normalize hook seems pretty same.

Comment: @ahmed `extractArray` you extract the array from payload (ie when using findAll()), and `extractSingle` you extract the single object (ie when using find()). `normalize`  i'm not too sure either, I actually don't ever have use it at all.